New route doesn't exist
I have added new route to my api.php
Route::get('/test', [WebinarController::class, 'index']);
I have also added use App\Http\Controllers\WebinarController; to my api.php
And I have created new controller WebinarController where I return "it works";
When I go to Postman and call http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/test
I get 404.
When I call http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/get-languages (older route)
I get collection:
"languages": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "en",
        "language": "english",
        "image_name": "en.png",
        "created_at": "2022-11-22T13:05:32.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-11-22T13:05:32.000000Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "de",
        "language": "german",
        "image_name": "de.png",
        "created_at": "2022-11-22T13:05:32.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-11-22T13:05:32.000000Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "sr",
        "language": "serbian",
        "image_name": "sr.png",
        "created_at": "2022-11-22T13:05:32.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-11-22T13:05:32.000000Z"
    }
]


Did you clear the route cache?

php artisan cache:clear I did this

A common command to clear and optimize various aspects of a Laravel application is:
php artisan optimize

This command is used to optimize the framework's performance by caching various components. It will also work to clear the route and cache clear.
We can also use the manual commands to solve this:
php artisan route:clear
php artisan cache:clear


I solved it with typing
php artisan route:clear
php artisan cache:clear

Thanks Gert B
